# Привязка кнопки веб-элемента к кнопке на клавиатуре

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, как привязать событие нажатия на кнопку button к кнопке на клавиатуре?

```
<button id="buttonForF12"> Перейти к F12</button>
```

По итогу я хочу получить такую реализацию, чтобы по нажатию на веб-элемент  мышкой происходило то же, что произошло если бы я нажала "F12" на клавиатуре ПК.

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/keyboard-events

Comment: может наоборот ?

Comment: Что за бред? Почему минус? Данный вопрос не является дубликатом. Зачем минусить, если для вас этот вопрос является элементарным? Я же не синьорам задаю эти вопросы, просто хочу разобраться!!! Этот ресурс для того чтобы разбираться, а не сливать.

Comment: хотите разобраться - пишите мне, правьте вопрос, а не ищите минусующих

Comment: @qwabra Правила вопрос.

Comment: я у вас спрашиваю, уже после вашей правки. ©может наоборот ? – qwabra 10 минут назад

Comment: Извините, не заметила. Нет, не наоборот.

Comment: если всё так, как вы написали, нам нужно знать что у вас происходит по нажатию на "F12" и как достучаться до этой функции

Comment: У меня вот на F12 ничего не происходит. А что у вас происходит? И как вы добьетесь того, что у вас у разных людей будет одинаковое действие происходить при нажатии на кнопку? Даже если бы такое было теоретически возможно

Comment: @qwabra,  у меня есть функция, которая выполняется и выводит результат в консоль. В *.html я создала блок, в котором находится кнопка. По нажатию на кнопку "F12" (в chrome)  у меня открываются инструменты разработчика.

Comment: @qwabra Хочу для красоты сделать элемент-кнопку, чтобы открывая *.html видеть не пустой экран, а элемент <button> - кнопка, которая предлагает перейти в консоль и увидеть результат работы программы.

Comment: @ArchDemon это не для большого круга пользователей, только для меня. Возникла идея, хочу реализовать ее, просто пока не знаю как.

Comment: Браузер, может перехватывать события нажатия клавиш. Но он вам не позволит генерировать нажатие клавиш и пробрасывать их в ОС. Это не безопасно. С такой возможностью можно удалить данные с диска путём нажатия клавиш, например.

Comment: @Yiulia, вы пишите расширение для хрома? если нет - то это невозможно

Comment: @qwabra, нет, это обычная js программка,жаль что это невозможно, спасибо за ответы, еще вопрос: у меня есть 1 приложение, которое я параллельно пишу- расширение для хрома и Ваш ответ меня заинтересовал, т.е. если я пишу расширение, то сделать это возможно? как?

Comment: @ArchDemon, спасибо, я Вас поняла.

Comment: @Yiulia, https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=112277 "We only allow explicit devtools opening." - судя по всему, и в расширении это не доступно.

Comment: @qwabra спасибо за ответы!

Comment: @Yiulia, если вам всего-навсего необходимо показать пользователю вывод консоли - можно поискать библиотечку или написать перехват `console.log` с использованием например `Proxy` https://learn.javascript.ru/proxy

Comment: @qwabra, отлично, спасибо, попробую реализовать.

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению это не сработает в целях безопасности Javascript, хотя если после нажатия должно выполнится событие внутри приложения (сайта) то имеется решение привязки к одной функции.

```js
function toggleBg() 
{
  alert("test");
}

document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event){
  if (event.keyCode == 112)
  {
    toggleBg();
  }
});
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleBg()">Нажмите здесь или на F1 что-бы запустить тестовую функцию</button>
```